# Reading movie from external source or updating assets

Tags: unity-game-engine

I`m developing an app that contains many movies. After the release of the app to user there is a possibility that one of the movies will be changed. The whole app is about 800 MB, and each movie is approximately 10 MB. There is any way to read the movies from folder in c:\ instead of putting them into assets folder, so I can send to user only the movie to change in the folder? Or there is possibility to some how to update the assets folder after release? Because I do not wish to send to user the whole 800 MB each time i change something small in the app. Some update tool.

Comment: You will have to provide some kind of streaming service to the user, from a server.

Comment: Did you look at [AssetBundles](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html)? In [LoadFromCacheOrDownload](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload.html) you can specify a version to use at least when accessing the bundle from cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an asset bundle that includes the videos that you need.

Maybe have it broken down into more than one asset bundle so that each is a small block.

Set up an foreach/iterator that would cycle through and download the asset bundles or pull from cache.

Have this set to interate a set number of times (i).

Before this script runs, have an xml set up on your server that contains 2 items. One titled 'change' and one titled 'amount'.

Each time the app is launched pull the xml, this will be tiny so you dont need to worry about any lag. Have it check the 'change' value and compare it to one stored locally on your app. If they match do nothing. If however they do not match then you can run the foreach/iterator for 'i' amount of times and set 'i' to the amount you have set in the xml.

THis way if you ever have an update, upload the new asset bundles to your server, and update the xml changing the 'change' to a new number and the 'amount' by the original amount + the amount of new asset bundles.

remember to update the value of 'changed' on the local device and save it as well.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload.html

```
WWW www = new WWW("http://yourserver/unity/check_for_update.xml");
```

CHeers